# Bounty notification appears multiple times

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, notifications

I don't know whether this is related to the [new notification system](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications/) or not, but I got 10 notifications and counting about the same event — the three-day notice for a bounty — about an hour apart. From https://meta.stackoverflow.com/notices/genuwine (copy-pasted, truncated and indented):

```
[{
  "is_unread":false,
  "text":"Your bounty on question \"\u003ca href=\"https://meta.stackoverflow.com/messages/mark-as-read?messagetypeid=6&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2f53322%2fclosed-then-merged-question-missing-merged-to-footer\"\u003eClosed-then-merged question missing &ldquo;merged to&rdquo; footer\u003c/a\u003e\" expires within three days.",
  "site_url":"http://meta.stackoverflow.com",
  "icon":"https://meta.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico",
  "created":"7 mins ago"
 },{
  "is_unread":false,
  "text":"Your bounty on question \"\u003ca href=\"https://meta.stackoverflow.com/messages/mark-as-read?messagetypeid=6&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2f53322%2fclosed-then-merged-question-missing-merged-to-footer\"\u003eClosed-then-merged question missing &ldquo;merged to&rdquo; footer\u003c/a\u003e\" expires within three days.",
  "site_url":"http://meta.stackoverflow.com",
  "icon":"https://meta.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico",
  "created":"1 hour ago"
 },{
  "is_unread":false,
  "text":"Your bounty on question \"\u003ca href=\"https://meta.stackoverflow.com/messages/mark-as-read?messagetypeid=6&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2f53322%2fclosed-then-merged-question-missing-merged-to-footer\"\u003eClosed-then-merged question missing &ldquo;merged to&rdquo; footer\u003c/a\u003e\" expires within three days.",
  "site_url":"http://meta.stackoverflow.com",
  "icon":"https://meta.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico",
  "created":"2 hours ago"
 },{
  "is_unread":false,
  "text":"Your bounty on question \"\u003ca href=\"https://meta.stackoverflow.com/messages/mark-as-read?messagetypeid=6&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2f53322%2fclosed-then-merged-question-missing-merged-to-footer\"\u003eClosed-then-merged question missing &ldquo;merged to&rdquo; footer\u003c/a\u003e\" expires within three days.",
  "site_url":"http://meta.stackoverflow.com",
  "icon":"https://meta.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico",
  "created":"3 hours ago"
 }, …
```

Screenshot(From [@yoda](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/160166/yoda)'s inbox):
[image]

Comment: I have this same problem. I even got 2 emails for the same bounty, within an hour.

Comment: Another email just now, 3 times for same one.

Comment: After further [undesired] research, the notification occurs every hour. [Make it stoppppp](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V5ITowWn6Dg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A fix for this will be rolling out in a build being deployed shortly.  When we moved the messages to a central location the "does this notice exist check" for bounties wasn't behaving...it will be after the next build.

Comment: I confirm that there is a single entry for this bounty in my notification box now.

Comment: Any chance the fix caused [such a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152309/152859)?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - nope, that's because the message code was not ever updated for non-owner bounties, just fixed though.