# "Your Bounty is Ending Soon" email / "Your bounty on question X expires in the next 24 hours" notification spam

Tags: bug, bounties, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bounty notification appears twice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133567/bounty-notification-appears-twice)

I have a bounty ending soon.  I know this because for the last 13 hours I've gotten:

- 1 email per hour with "Bounty Ending Soon" in the subject line
- 1 "supercollider notification tab" reminder about it per hour "Your bounty on question X expires in the next 24 hours"

I certainly hope this isn't by design - this is an *awful lot* of reminders.  Would someone take a look into this and tell me what's going on with it or if it's by design?