# Duplicate notification about a suggested edit to one of my posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, notifications

Somebody [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/279925) to one of my posts. I got sent *two* notifications about it to my inbox:

[image: Double notification]

Both notifications link to the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/279925) suggested edit and seem to be identical. The edit was already rejected when I noticed the notifications.

Probably only one notification should be sent.

Comment: probably [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133567/160166) again, in a different form...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happened here is that edit was suggested, then updated before being approved/rejected.  My code erroneously considered both to be notification worthy.

Starting with the next build only strictly new edit suggestions will result in notifications.