# Other people's expired bounties on your question trigger Notifications

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, notifications

I just got a notification of "You bounty on question [THIS](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87188/can-i-skip-cutscenes-in-xcom-enemy-unknown) has completed - answer auto-selected"

Only problem is, it wasn't my bounty.

Comment: Maybe [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137853/notify-me-when-a-bounty-is-placed-on-one-of-my-questions) has been silently implemented? :-)

Comment: By the way did you get any notification *before* that? E.g. when the bounty was placed or about to expire?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Not to my knowledge, no. Checking through my inbox, it doesn't appear to be in there either.

Comment: Weird either way.. I assume a bug/glitch following some recent change.  [Candidate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133567/bounty-notification-appears-multiple-times/133639#133639)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like non-owner bounties were never accounted for in the "who to message" code.  The next deploy will send the message to the bounty owner as should be the case.